# Как отключить fpu в прерываниях?

Tags: c++, gnu, fpu

Есть файл с обработчиками прерываний. Все функции определены с атрибутом `[[gnu::interrupt]]`. Если глобально отключить генерирование fpu387 и SSE команд, то всё компилируется. Если же разрешить использование fpu387 и/или SSE, то возникает ошибка

> sorry, unimplemented: MMX/3Dnow instructions aren't allowed in interrupt

.

С SSE вопрос решается прагмой: `#pragma GCC target "no-mmx,no-sse"`
Но это не работает в отношении 80387:

> sorry, unimplemented: 80387 instructions aren't allowed in interrupt service routine

Искал в поисковиках, но не нашёл решения как указать на то, что в данном файле вообще вещественные числа не используются.
В инструкции к GCC про отключение кода fpu387 только в параметрах компилятора (`-mno-80387`), то есть глобально.

Как вариант: выключил глобально. Включаю в общем заголовочном файле прагмой: `#pragma GCC target("sse")`
В файле указываю `#pragma GCC target("no-sse")`. Результат:

> sorry, unimplemented: SSE instructions aren't allowed in interrupt
>   service routine'

То есть прагма была успешно проигнорирована.

Пример кода (это только пример!) https://godbolt.org/z/kLVdWE

Comment: Что значит:  В инструкции к GCC про отключение кода fpu387 только в параметрах компилятора (-mno-80387), то есть глобально? Что вам мешает задать компилятору этот флаг для нужного файла, откомпилировать, а остальное компилировать без флага? Вы же сами сказали,что это нужно для целого файла.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch пробовал такой вариант. Не работает. Предупреждений про игнорирование нет, но и компилироваться не хочет.

Comment: нет такого понятия: не хочет - есть ошибка компиляции. Что за ошибка?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch ИМХО, именно не хочет. Если в прерывании нельзя использовать вещественные числа, то разработчики компилятора должны были предусмотреть отключение этого кода по-умолчанию. Ошибку написал в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл способ. Честно говоря, это можно назвать извращением, но сработало.
Смысл в том, что изначально запрещаются все операции с вещественными числами, параметры `-mno-mmx -mno-sse -mno-80387`

В нужных файлах определяются вначале все функции, которым вещественные числа не нужны.
Необходимо добавить описание всех функций, которые работают с вещественными числами заранее. Думаю, это и так понятно.

В конце указывается компилятору включить компилятору команды для работы с вещественными числами и определяются все функции, которым нужна такая поддержка.

Пример: https://godbolt.org/z/f4MpoY